# Powershell handling CSV file

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

Let's say I have this CSV file

```
customer 60; SomeLocation; 60
customer 120; SomeLocation; 120
customer 140; SomeLocation; 140
customer 200; SomeLocation; 200
customer 300; SomeLocation; 300
```

I'm importing using Import-CSV. I'm able to walk through every line and filter each property using pre-set headers. 
I want to set a target, let's say 140. I want to use $random to pick some line, let's say

`customer 200; SomeLocation; 200`
Now, as 200 is bigger than 140, I want to remove it from memory (not from the CSV), but looks like I'm having an issue understanding how can I manipulate Arrays, since I'm getting `Collection was of a fixed size.` all the way.

I know how to do the random stuff, but I'm struggling finding out a way to import the CSV and use it freely.

Comment: Your .csv file does not seem right. The first line have to be headers (separated with a delimiter), the 2nd to nth line have to be values (separated with a delimiter). Using `import-csv` is correct, try and also define `-delimiter` parameter. Also post your code with which you are trying to manipulate the array.

Comment: Both `Import-CSV` and `ConvertFrom-CSV` support the `-Header` parameter to define headerless csvs so the lack of header in the csv itself is not really a problem here.

Comment: Please add more info, your question isn't clear. From what I can see though, you may want to look into piping into a "Where-object" to re-import your CSV based on conditions.

Answer (score 1):

See the example below.

Using `Get-Content` and `ConvertFrom-CSV` with its `-header` parameter to define the csv headers since they are not present in your CSV, you can get an object out of the data.

Then, instead of trying to remove stuff to the original array, you instead build an output "array" using an object which you can modify freely, such as the .net list object.

From there, you can do what you want.

```
$CsvData = @'
customer 60; SomeLocation; 60
customer 120; SomeLocation; 120
customer 140; SomeLocation; 140
customer 200; SomeLocation; 200
customer 300; SomeLocation; 300
'@

# In your case, rather than the direct csv data, you'd use
#$CsvData = Get-Content -Path 'PATH_TO_THE_CSV' -Raw

$Customers = ConvertFrom-Csv $CsvData -Delimiter ';' -Header 'CustomerName','Location','SomeInt'

# Not sure why you'd use it if you set your target to 140
$Random = Get-Random -InputObject $Customers

# We build a new List instead of trying to remove from the original object.
$CustomersOutput = [System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]]::new()
#Arbitrary filtering - Notice I do convert SomeInt to an int before doing the comparison. 
# Otherwise, the comparison would be done between a string and an int, which would produce weird results. 
$Customers.Where( { [int]$_.SomeInt -le 140 }) | % { $CustomersOutput.Add($_) }

$CustomersOutput
```

Result from `$CustomerOutput`
[image: Results]